# LPC FMC to FPGA pin mapping on the Zedboard

Tags: fpga, xilinx

Does anybody know anything about how to map fpga pins to actual physical pin on the FMC connector on a Zedboard?

Of course I have looked into the user's hardware guide and the master constraint file, but all I have found id a list of the FMC pins out on the FPGA side but nothing on how it is mapped to the LPC FMC pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Though there is no table, you can find this info on the schematics. Check the schematic of the FMC on:

http://zedboard.org/sites/default/files/documentations/ZedBoard_RevD.2_Schematic_130516.pdf

and match the pins with the labels in the master UCF file.